# Mysql insert into statement works everywhere except node js client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This is the code I run:

```
con.query(`INSERT INTO osumulti.users VALUES ('${discordid.toString()}', '${osuid.toString()}')`, (err, result) => { if(err){throw err} ;message.channel.send("Operation successfull! | " + JSON.stringify(result)) })
```

The module works with everything else, I'm only having problems with INSERT statements. I don't get any errors, but nothing changes, here's the result I get back, from running this:

```
{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":2,"warningCount":0,"message":"(Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}
```

I ran the same query, only replacing the variables in mysql workbench and it worked perfectly! I also tried installing an older version of the node mysql client, but that doesn't allow me to log in to my server, so I'm stuck using the latest. I also tried installing a bugfix the author mentioned. but that didn't work either. What else can I try in this situation?

Comment: Try to define field names in query

Comment: Originally, they were defined, I removed them as an attempt to fix it.